# How to iteratively name dataset

Tags: r, for-loop, dataset

Here is an example of my code:

```
library(Rcpp)
library(readxl)

Sheets<-readxl::excel_sheets("~/data.xlsx")
sheet_names <- sheets[grepl("String", sheets, ignore.case=TRUE)

for (i in 1:length(sheet_names)){
    dataset[i] <- read_excel("data.xlsx", sheet = sheet_names[i])
}
```

What I would like this to do is to return a dataset named "dataset1" where i=1 and "dataset2" where i=2 and so on. Alternatively, I would like to use the name of the sheet itself i.e. sheet_names[i] but when attempting to use that it overwrites the strings in the variable.

I would be grateful for any suggestions on this.

Comment: Did you try this?
  
dataset <- read_excel(.....)   

assign(paste0("sheet_names_", i), dataset)

rm(dataset)

Comment: I've tried that now and it's worked a charm. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Consider storing the data in a list instead of creating multiple dataframes in global environment. These objects are difficult to manage and they pollute the global environment.

```
library(readxl)

Sheets <-  excel_sheets("~/data.xlsx")
sheet_names <- grep("String", sheets, ignore.case=TRUE, value = TRUE)
list_data <- lapply(sheet_names, function(x) read_excel("data.xlsx", sheet = x))
```

`list_data` is a list of dataframes. If you need to access individual dataframes you can use `list_data[[1]]` to get the 1st dataframe, `list_data[[2]]` to get the 2nd one and so on.